# Unit tests that are testing for View being returned are failing

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing

.Net 4.5 MVC application - Unit tests that are testing for View being returned are failing with an error indicating it cannot find System.Web.WebPages on our build server:

Error Message:

> Test method
>
> CCSSWorkflow.Tests.CAHDAResearchControllerTest.CAHDAResearchDetailMethodReturnsCorrectView threw exception:
>
> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'System.Web.Mvc.ViewEngines' threw an exception. ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.WebPages, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

These same tests run fine from Visual Studio, they also run fine from the command line on my local machine utilizing vstest.

These same tests (same SVN build number) ran fine yesterday.

I do not have direct access to the build server, but I can ask questions. So far they have indicated there was no changes to the server in last two days.

Answer (score 1):

Intermittent issues of that type may indicate missing binding redirect (it is possible that multiple project point to different versions and random sequence of loading at runtime may cause this).

If you have confirmed all references and binding redirects in your project are fine, and to take out the guess work out of the message you are seeing, ask them to enable Fusion on the build server - this will give you the details of what exactly is missing, if indeed you are dealing with a missing assembly.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I am checking with the server team to see if they can enable Fusion